# BackgroundFetch in Codename One

Tags: ios, codenameone

I'm developing a Codename One app for iOS and I'm trying to use the BackgroundFetch  interface.

I copied the sample code as it is written in Javadoc (https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/background/BackgroundFetch.html) and I added the **ios.background_modes=fetch** build hint.

Launching the app on the simulator, the background operation is correctly executed.

Launching it on a real device (iPhone 7s, iOs 12.1.4), the behaviour is unpredictable. Despite the `setPreferredBackgroundFetchInterval(10)`, I noticed almost every time I launch the app, the background operation is not executed. Rarely, the background operation is executed, but the app must be in background some minutes before to resume it, instead of 10 seconds, as set through the setPreferredBackgroundFetchInterval(10) method.

The `Display.isBackgroundFetchSupported()` method returns true.

I don't understand how to make if affordable and predictable.

---

EDIT

I modified the sample code, only in the performBackgroundFetch() implementation (the `Display.setPreferredBackgroundFetchInterval(10)` is not changed). I just put some text in the label:

```
@Override
public void performBackgroundFetch(long deadline, Callback<Boolean> onComplete) {
    supported.setText("deadline: " + deadline + "; timeMillis: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
    onComplete.onSucess(Boolean.TRUE);
}
```

I observed two different behaviours for simulator and real device.
In simulator, the method is executed exactly 10 seconds after entering in pause status. In real device, the method isn't executed 10 seconds after entering in pause status: in some cases, it's executed after 20 minutes (in other cases, it's not executed at all).
However, in both cases, I could calculate the difference between the deadline and the time when the method executed: it's always 25 minutes.

As an example, you can see the following screenshot of the app (running on iPhone):
[image]

Deadline = 1560246881647
Timestamp = 1560245381647

Deadline - Timestamp = 1500000 ms = 1500 s = 25 minutes.

As I understood, on iOS, there is a limit of 30 seconds to perform background fetches, otherwise the OS will kill the app. Moreover, the `Display.setPreferredBackgroundFetchInterval()` is used to set the preferred time interval between background fetches, but it's not guaranteed, as iOS keeps the control over the execution of background fetches.

What is the right way to use background fetch?

Here is the complete code:

```
public class MyApplication implements BackgroundFetch{

   private Form current;
   private Resources theme;
   List<Map> records;
   Label supported;
   // Container to hold the list of records.
   Container recordsContainer;

   public void init(Object context) {
      theme = UIManager.initFirstTheme("/theme");

      // Enable Toolbar on all Forms by default
      Toolbar.setGlobalToolbar(true);

      // Pro only feature, uncomment if you have a pro subscription
      // Log.bindCrashProtection(true);
   }

   public void start() {
      if(current != null){
         // Make sure we update the records as we are coming in from the 
         // background.
         updateRecords();
         current.show();
         return;
      }
      Display d = Display.getInstance();

      // This call is necessary to initialize background fetch
      d.setPreferredBackgroundFetchInterval(10);

      Form hi = new Form("Background Fetch Demo");
      hi.setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

      supported = new Label();
      if (d.isBackgroundFetchSupported()){
         supported.setText("Background Fetch IS Supported");
      } else {
         supported.setText("Background Fetch is NOT Supported");
      }

      hi.addComponent(new Label("Records:"));
      recordsContainer = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
      //recordsContainer.setScrollableY(true);
      hi.addComponent(recordsContainer);
      hi.addComponent(supported);
      updateRecords();
      hi.show();
  }

  /**
   * Update the UI with the records that are currently loaded.
   */
  private void updateRecords() {
     recordsContainer.removeAll();
     if (records != null) {
        for (Map m : records) {
            recordsContainer.addComponent(new SpanLabel((String)m.get("title")));
        }
     } else {
        recordsContainer.addComponent(new SpanLabel("Put the app in the background, wait 10 seconds, then open it again.  The app should background fetch some data from the Slashdot RSS feed and show it here."));
     }
     if (Display.getInstance().getCurrent() != null) {
        Display.getInstance().getCurrent().revalidate();
     }
  }

  public void stop() {
     current = Display.getInstance().getCurrent();
     if(current instanceof Dialog) {
        ((Dialog)current).dispose();
        current = Display.getInstance().getCurrent();
     }
  }

  public void destroy() {
  }

  /**
   * This method will be called in the background by the platform.  It will
   * load the RSS feed.  Note:  This only runs when the app is in the background.
   * @param deadline
   * @param onComplete 
   */
  @Override
  public void performBackgroundFetch(long deadline, Callback<Boolean> onComplete) {
     supported.setText("deadline: " + deadline + "; timeMillis: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
     onComplete.onSucess(Boolean.TRUE);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `setPreferredBackgroundFetchInterval` javadoc states:

> Sets the preferred time interval between background fetches.  This is only a preferred interval and is not guaranteed.  Some platforms, like iOS, maintain sovereign control over when and if background fetches will be allowed. *This number is used only as a guideline*.

Comment: I don't understand. I only set one parameter, through Display.setPreferredBackgroundFetchInterval(). That values is in seconds. You are talking about the deadline: how can I set it? If so, the sample code is wrong.

Comment: What did you set at the background fetch deadline when invoking `performBackgroundFetch`?

Comment: As I wrote in the question, I copied the sample code of BackgroundFetch. I didn't set any value to deadline and I don't know how to do it.

Comment: I revised my answer, `setPreferredBackgroundFetchInterval` is used only as a guideline and provides no guarantees

Comment: In other words, this mechanism is not affordable. We can't be sure about its execution. I don't understand: about deadline, it is said "On iOS, there is a limit of 30 seconds to perform background fetches"; why do I often observe the background execution starts after 20 minutes?

Comment: Limit means that if your download doesn't finish in 30 seconds it will be killed... Of course it isn't reliable, it's meant as a stopgap. With apps your core functionality must be accomplished in the foreground.